# My embed video is not playing in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I want to play this video in webview in android 
http://www.youtube.com/embed/hLw8RZ10PLo?showsearch=0&autoplay=1&rel=0

But searched for it and i have implemented everything what i got

here is my code

```
package com.example.webapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        final WebSettings.PluginState ON = webSettings.getPluginState().ON;
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.766.0 Safari/534.36");

        webSettings.setPluginState(ON);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/hLw8RZ10PLo?showsearch=0&autoplay=1&rel=0");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

}
```

and this is my xml

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview" >

</WebView>
```

I am playing this video in my **android 2.3.6** version and in my manifest file, I have used

```
android:harwareAccelerated="true"
```

But still my video is not running.
Can Anybody help me, I  am stuck in this problem from yesterday.

Comment: When i run my application it shows a player and the total time of video but it doesnot start.

Answer (score 0):

Use Webview, Create a string for html tags, add iframe tage and pass the height and width of the video and url. and load the string in webview

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Add the string in loaddata of webview

```
webView.loadData(strHTMLTags, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Its a string, i named like that. load your html tags in that string and load in webview

Comment: I used iframe in webview but still my video is not playing. When i run my application it shows a player and the total time of video but it doesnot start.